# Python storing number with leading zeros in Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, leading-zero

I have a dictionary called table. I want to assign this number to the below dic key. it keeps giving me an error saying "invalid token". I have tried converting it string, int, and float but to no avail

`table['Fac_ID'] = 00000038058`

Comment: can you post full code segment please?

Comment: So what's the problem with converting to string?

Comment: because you're enabling octal mode with a 8 in it. use strings instead

Comment: Like many other languages, in python a leading zero indicates octal, base 8, 0-7.    You have an 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't convert it to a string, use it as a string in the first place:

```
>>> table['Fac_ID'] = str(00000038058)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    table['Fac_ID'] = str(00000038058)
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
>>> table['Fac_ID'] = '00000038058'
>>> print table['Fac_ID']
00000038058
```

str, as any function, evaluates the argument to a value before passing it in, so if there was an invalid token before str, using str is not going to change that. You need to use a valid token, so just hardcode the string.

Comment: technically python evaluates the argument before passing it to the function, but yes.

Comment: I wouldn't store numbers as string because first it takes more memory and second what if someone enters a bad padding? 2 identical integer values but 2 different string values.

Comment: If it was user input or the like the asker wouldn't be getting an invalid token error in the first place - he was clearly trying to hardcode the values.

Answer (score 2):

you're unwilingly invoking Python 2.x octal mode but:

- you can't because there's a 8 in it (bad or good luck?)
- in python 3 (also works in python 2.7), octal prefix is no longer `0` but `0o`: invalid token occurs because of that.

It would be better to store your values without leading zeroes and add the leading zeroes when you print them

```
print("%012d"%table['Fac_ID'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Surround the number in quotes.

table['Fac_ID'] = "00000038058"

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`zfill`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.zfill) to pad zeros.  Assuming you want to pad up to 11 zeroes:

```
>>> str(38058).zfill(11)
'00000038058'
```

This obviously creates a zero padded string to be used as the key based on an integer.